# Synology DSM Backup - configuration file

Tags: linux, backup, synology

I have 2 NAS DSM Synology 5.1 system and I want to make daily Network BackUp of first DSM to second one.

I am using Backup&Recovery tool from DSM GUI (aready have created shared folders, granted permission etc.) and when I go to the part where I can choose Shared folders I do not have option to select all shared folders (I can only pick one by one) and that is the problem - because if I create a new share folder, that new folder is not included in the next BackUP.

I have found configuration file (synobackup.conf) and in that file is:

```
backup_folders=["/folder1", "/folder2", "/folder3", "/folder4", "/folder5"]
```

So my question is:
How can I include all shared folders (existing folders and new created) to scheduled BackUp.

Can I type any command in "backup_folders=["XXX"] to select all shared folders. I have tried with *, $ but it does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: you could try setting up a python script to edit the conf file daily ?

Comment: Can you point me on some kind of tutorial?
I can't see in my usr/bin folder python folder

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get a time backup or a total backup.
Timebackups are more advanced then the default software, But therefor you have the option of restoring all the data. 
A total backup is in case our NAS dies and have to reïnstall the OS.